# Using Conditionals and Time & Date in Assembly Language

Tags: date, if-statement, assembly, time, x86-16

I'm new with assembly language (8086 Program) and I am trying to create a program that display a greeting depending on system date and time. Like if the system date is December 25 then the program will print "Merry Christmas" or if January 1 then it's "Happy New Year". If it just a regular day / no holiday then just print a "Good day". On system time, probably display a "Good Evening" or "Good Morning".

So far, I learned how to get and display the system time and date. Now, I am wondering how can I apply conditionals (if-else) on it.

Comment: You should show your code, or be more precise, else: it is difficult to answer.

Comment: Doing conditionals can be a bit tricky at first, since they're written in a different manner than most high-level languages. In assembly your control flow is in terms of `goto` rather than curly braces.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you've asked the date from DOS using function 2Bh, the day will be in DL and the month in DH. Checking for Christmas day is simply writing `cmp dx, 0C19h`.
Get inspired by next example:

```
  mov  si, Xmas
  cmp  dx, 0C19h  ; 25 dec
  je   GoPrint
  mov  si, NewY
  cmp  dx, 0101h  ; 01 jan
  je   GoPrint

  ...

GoPrint:
  mov  dx, si
  mov  ah, 09h   ; DOS.PrintString
  int  21h

  ...

Xmas: db 'Merry ...', 13, 10, '$'
NewY: db 'Happy ...', 13, 10, '$'
```

For 'Good day' vs 'Good evening', you can apply similar code to the time (hours) in the CH register that you get from invoking the DOS function 2Ch.